Azure devops Databricks Terraform "cannot configure default credentials"
I'm trying to create release which do some magic with terraform but i stuck when i trying to apply changes.
When i pushing it from desktop it working fine, but i do it with managed identity from azure devops it's crash.
I did step by step instruction https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/oauth-m2m.html#language-Terraform
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.62.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      "source" = "databricks/databricks"
      version  = "~>1.34"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "databricks" {
  alias         = "workspace"
  host          = "adb-xxxxxxxxx.azuredatabricks.net"
  client_id     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

data "databricks_jobs" "this" {}

resource "databricks_permissions" "everyone_can_view_all_jobs" {
  for_each = data.databricks_jobs.this.ids
  job_id   = each.value

  access_control {
    group_name       = "xxxxxxxxx"
    permission_level = "CAN_MANAGE"
  }
  access_control {
    permission_level       = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    service_principal_name = var.adf_id_for_env
  }
}

I tried use Terraform task and Azure Powershell and both give me these same error.
read jobs: cannot read data jobs: default auth: cannot configure default credentials, please check https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth.html#databricks-client-unified-authentication to configure credentials for your preferred authentication method. Config: azure_use_msi=true, azure_tenant_id=xxxxxxxxx. Env: ARM_USE_MSI, ARM_TENANT_ID
cannot read data jobs: default auth: cannot configure default credentials, please check https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth.html#databricks-client-unified-authentication to configure credentials for your preferred authentication method
I want to make it work, for powershell scripts i have something like this to recognize environment, but there is no way to force it in terraform.
databricks jobs create --json @C:/Jobs/$_ -p 'TEST'


Check databricks provider authentication. PS: Do you need azurerm provider?
